# How to drag and move node in ARCore?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I put an AnchorNode 0.9 meter away from camera.

```
val anchor = frag.arSceneView.session.createAnchor(pose)
val node = TransformableNode(system)
node.renderable = renderable
node.setParent(root)
```

I can't move the node when no plane is detected on the table.

**How can I let the node move by dragging in the infinite horizontal table plane?**

Comment: Unless the table plane is detected , you cannot move node beyond the detected plane

Comment: Hey @Henry, have you got any solution? I am having the same question as you asked but didn't get any solution.

Comment: use your own logic to do this on button click add x,y,or z axis in current position model can be moved any where by doing this.